# Can I use double version keys in script src attribute to avoid browser cache

Tags: html

Is the below code cause any issue? 
Is the browser take the updated version of js without clearing cache?

Comment: <script src="xxx/yyy/test. js?v=1?version=2342" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't cause any issue because you are just passing Get Query String Parameters on JS url but why would you do that? It's better to .., just increment the value of v=1

Try adding this on your browser address bar and reload the page it won't cause any issue.

`?xx=test`

Sample : https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript?aaaaaa=bbbbbbbb?ccccccccccc=ddddddddddddd

Comment: So everytime there's an update on your JS you should update those Get Query String Parameters on your JS url then your browser should automatically take the updated version of your js without clearing cache

Comment: Thank you... I am increasing?version value, then dose the browser take new version of test.js from server?

Comment: yes just increase the version value every-time there's an update on your JS

Comment: @RamyaM if this helps.. can u mark it as answer thanks